# Full path of production conf file in Windows

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

I'm trying to start the application in production mode with the following command:

```
myapp.bat -Dconfig.resource=c:\mydir\prod\prod.conf
```

I specified the full path of `prod.conf` but Play doesn't find it. I also tried with quotes and forward slashes. The file is there, how is this supposed to work?

Comment: It seems that the `myapp.bat` is a windows batch file. But the argument that you pass needs to be passed to the java command. You need to get the arguments at myapp.bat and pass them to the underlying java command.

Comment: `myapp.bat` is the bat generated by Play, according to the documentation you specify `-Dconfig.resource` in the same command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Play Documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ProductionConfiguration#Specifying-an-alternate-configuration-file) `-Dconfig.resource` is used for Resources from the classpath.

Try using `-Dconfig.file=c:\mydir\prod\prod.conf`

Here is another a bit more involved solution:

Verified for **Play 2.6:**

We use an `application.ini` that is used by the Linux start script.

Example:

```
-J-Xmx1024M
-J-Xms512M
-Dconfig.file=/mydir/prod/prod.conf
```

The Windows start script handles some stuff a bit different, so we created a `windows-installer.bat` that makes changes to it.

Here the code:

```
@ECHO OFF
pushd %~dp0
REM This file is needed if you want to run the service on a Windows machine.
REM the custom variables that must be adjusted for each project.
@REM SET project=PROJECT-NAME (directory name of the project)
SET project=
FOR %%* in (..) do SET project=%%~nx*
SET search=-
SET replace=_
CALL SET project=%%project:%search%=%replace%%%

@REM other variables
@REM SET home=C:\opt\scala-adapters\%project%
pushd ..
SET home=%CD%
pushd %~dp0

SET driveletter=%CD:~0,2%

@REM --------------------set project name---------------------------------------
SET projecttmp=
SET /p projecttmp="Default project name is [%project%], ENTER if correct otherwise insert project name here: "
IF NOT [%projecttmp%] == [] (
  SET project=%projecttmp%
  )
@REM ---------------------------------------------------------------------------


@REM --------------------set project home path----------------------------------
SET hometmp=
SET /p hometmp="Default project home folder is [%home%], ENTER if correct otherwise insert path here: "
IF NOT [%hometmp%] == [] (
  IF EXIST "%hometmp%" (
    SET home="%hometmp%"
   ) ELSE (
   ECHO !!!!! Your path "%hometmp%" does not exist. Exit!
   PAUSE
   EXIT /B
   )
) 
@REM ---------------------------------------------------------------------------


@REM -------------------------Settings SUMMARY----------------------------------
ECHO +++ Your project name is "%project%"
ECHO +++ Your path is "%home%"
@REM ---------------------------------------------------------------------------


@REM -------------------------create config file--------------------------------
SET file=%home%\%project%_config.txt
SET appini=%home%\conf\application.ini

@REM remove the '-J' prefix that is not needed by Windows.
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
set "search=-J"
set "replace="

IF EXIST "%appini%" (
    @REM Copy the application.ini (created by the build process)
    ECHO copy /y  %appini% %file%
    copy /y  %appini% %file%

    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%file%" ^& break ^> "%file%" ') do (
       set "line=%%i"
       setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
       set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
       >>"%file%" echo(!line!
       endlocal
    )
    ECHO ===%file% created
) ELSE (
    ECHO !!!!! there is no file at %appini%. EXIT!
    PAUSE
    EXIT /B
)
@REM ---------------------------------------------------------------------------


PAUSE
```

If you have both in your `conf` directory of your deployed Application this should work. Sorry I have no Windows environment anymore.

Make sure you change the PROJECT-NAME.

Comment: you use `-Dconfig.file` instead of `-Dconfig.resource` in 2.5?

Comment: Now I use 2.6, but I cannot remember that this changed during migration.
Here is the explanation: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ProductionConfiguration#Specifying-an-alternate-configuration-file
I updated my answer.